# opencl barrier not working

Tags: java, parallel-processing, opencl

Why doesnt this barrier work.
This should produce the numbers 1-length in the output array with their sum in output[0]. If i lower the loop scale this works correctly. With a high scale the threads should wait at the barrier but dont, producing incorrect output.

```
__kernel void b_test1( __global int* a, int length) {
int id = get_global_id(0);
const int scale = 100;
for (int i=0; i< id*scale; i++) a[id]=0; /* useless loops scaled up by id, just to waste time. note more time is wasted with bigger id */
a[id]=id;

barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

if (id==0){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++){
        sum+=a[i];
    }
    a[0]=sum;
}
}
```

my java code

```
    CLContext context = JavaCL.createBestContext();
    CLQueue queue = context.createDefaultQueue();

    CLProgram program = context.createProgram(ReadText.readText(new File("src/kernel1.c")));
    CLKernel kernel = program.createKernel("b_test1");

    int length=10;
    CLIntBuffer input = context.createIntBuffer(CLMem.Usage.InputOutput, length);

    kernel.setArgs(input, length);
    CLEvent event =  kernel.enqueueNDRange(queue, new int[]{length}, new int[]{1});
    queue.finish();

    IntBuffer output = input.read(queue, event);
    String out="";
    for (int i=0; i< length; i++){
        out+=output.get()+"\t";
    }
    System.out.println(out);
```

Thanks.

Edit: I've run this on win7 nvidia gtx 275 v270.61 opencl1.0 & Ubuntu nvidia 8600M GS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization functions operate on all threads *inside a single workgroup*.  Workgroups are executed independently in an unspecified order.

To synchronize different workgroups, you have to run different kernels, and specify a dependency between them (via events, or barriers).

Comment: ah thanks, so i need to create the event like `CLEvent event =  kernel.enqueueNDRange(queue, new int[]{length}, new int[]{length});`